# OCX File registered, but.. not registered?

Tags: c++, com, ocx

So the setup is as follows:

1. I have an Access VBA project which I have to maintain until we move everything over onto a new shiny platform.
2. This VBA project contains numerous reports, which use a .OCX charting component. This component was written about 15 years ago in C++. I have access to the code, but it won't compile right now because I can't get my hands on the correct version of the toolchain used to create it. At some point I may end up actually reworking the code just to get it to compile.
3. I can register the OCX using regsvr32, BUT:

   - Curious Thing. If I use the /i switch with regsvr32 like you're supposed to, it doesn't work. It says something about not finding an entry point.
   - If I use it without the /i switch, it seems to go off without a hitch. I see entries in the registry for the ocx file with the correct location etc.
4. When I run the Access code and generate a report, I get a "this control does not contain an Object" error when I attempt to call into a property of the OCX class I'm using called "Object".

Does anyone have any ideas?

What I have tried:

- I've tried removing and re-adding the reference. Still no go.
- I've used OLEViewer to peek at the component, but when I try to View Type Information it gives me "Library not loaded".

Comment: Shot in the dark: 32/64 bit issue? Like, you are registering it with the "wrong" regsvr32, or it's a 32 bit component but you are trying to use it from a 64 bit application or something similar?

Comment: Actually that could be it. I popped open the OCX in Dependency Walker and it's showing a lot of issues with library functions missing.Only thing is, it's working on some of my colleagues' machines, so it must be possible somehow to configure the thing to run correctly.

Comment: Maybe you installed 64 bit Access, while they installed the 32 bit version?

Comment: Did you call regsvr32 from an elevated (administrator) command prompt?  Is it possible there is another copy of the OCX in your path?  I ask because regsvr32 searches the path (believe it or not) and will choose a file in the path over the one in the local directory unless you qualify the path to your OCX.  Where exactly is the TLB for this OCX?  It's a big red flag that it can't be opened in OLE/COM Object Viewer. Of course be sure to use the right bitness version of oleview.exe.

Comment: Hmm not sure what bitness I'm using actually. Must check for that. And yes I'm running the command prompt as admin.

Comment: I can't find a 64-bit version of oleview, actually. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's in the Windows SDK (8.1 for me).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the SDK.

Comment: Dependency Walker is badly out of date and gives loads of spurious errors nowadays. Try DependenciesGUI (a .NET replacement) instead.